# Opening a Link in a new window from a dynamic navigation link

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a CMS site that uses dynamic navigation. There is one link on the site that I would like to be able to open in a new window. However, since this is a dynamic environment I can't add the standard, **target="_blank"** to the link.

Resorting to Javascript I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open ('http://www.foo.edu/education/global-health-courses', 'newwindow',   config='height=800, width=700')
 </script>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work properly. I could use a little Javascript magic to have this work properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about your browser configuration? In my case it works, maybe you have some adblock/popup limitations?

You can also try with jQuery which supports more browsers than plain javascript (usually)...

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: I forgot to include the fact that this needs to be tied to a specific link in the navigation.

Comment: This answer was close, but I got the full answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095968/jquery-to-open-link-in-new-window-not-working/2096025#2096025

Comment: sorry, i was not enough detailed :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the proper window name and you should be fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.open ("http://www.foo.edu/", "_blank", "height=800, width=700");
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Paulo, I just realized that I missed a very, very important aspect of this problem. I need this to be associated with one specific link in the navigation. How do I do that part?

Comment: If you can access the onClick property, simply put the code in it. However, if you don't, but have access to JQuery, use it.

Comment: you can see jquery example in my answer.

if you have link:

<a id="mylink" href="http://stackoverflow.com">SO</a> 

you can use
$("#mylink").attr("target", "_blank");