# jQuery to open link in new window not working

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic navigation and need to open one link in a new window.

As such I am using jQuery to help, but the following code does not seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('a[href="http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/education/global-health-courses"]').attr("target", "_blank");
</script>
```

To try it for yourself: http://globalhealth-dev.oit.duke.edu/education/ then click on the Global Health Courses link under Education.

I would appreciate some help getting this to work properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection part of your script is wrong, namely the href that should match the href in the  element. Try with this:
`$('a[href="/education/global-health-courses"]').attr("target", "_blank");`

Also note that it is not recommended to select that link using href as it is slower than just using a id in the  element and then using $("a#myid").

Also be careful to call this only when the document is done loading:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href="/education/global-health-courses"]').attr("target", "_blank");    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $('a').attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

You need to wait for the DOM to be ready. Also placing the actual link attribute doesn't seem like a very maintainable/reusable idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `<a>` is this:

```
<a href="/education/global-health-courses">Global Health Courses</a>
```

You can try doing a attribute match for "ends with" in the event that the href gets rewritten (which has been known to happen on some browsers) -- Also, you don't need the quotes around the attribute

```
// Use the "DOM Ready" event to delay execution until the page is loaded
// $(func) is a shortcut for $(document).ready(func)
$(function() {
  $('a[href$=/education/global-health-courses]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

It would be much better if you could add a class to the link to identify it as a open in new window link.